# No guarda la firma electrónica en MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Necesito guardar desde un formulario una firma electrónica pero no me permite guardar y eso que ya hice un `insert` y le puse un `name` a esa variante. me guarda todo pero la imagen de la firma electrónica no me guarda, solo me guarda el la imagen en la carpeta seleccionada pero no en la base de datos.

Este es mi código

```
<h2>Learn Infinity | jQuery Signature Pad & Canvas Image</h2>

    <div id="signArea"  name="firma">
        <h2 class="tag-ingo">Put signature below,</h2>
        <div class="sig sigWrapper" style="height:auto;">
            <div class="typed"></div>
            <canvas class="sign-pad" id="sign-pad" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="sign-container">
    <?php
    $image_list = glob("./doc_signs/*.png");
    foreach($image_list as $image){
        //echo $image;
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="sign-preview" />
    <?php

    }
    ?>
    </div>




        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="registrar" id="registrar" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-success">
        </div>
        <br>
        <span id="result"></span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#signArea').signaturePad({drawOnly:true, drawBezierCurves:true, lineTop:90});
        });

        $("#registrar").click(function(e){
            html2canvas([document.getElementById('sign-pad')], {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var canvas_firma = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    var firma = canvas_firma.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
                    //ajax call to save image inside folder
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'sign_src/sign_src/save_sign.php',
                        data: { firma:firma },
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {
                           window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
      </script> 
</body>
</html>

<?php
require("scripts/conexion.php");    






$Id_u = $_SESSION["Id"];
$clv_e = isset($_POST['clv_e']) ? $_POST['clv_e'] : null;
$seccion = isset($_POST['seccion']) ? $_POST['seccion'] : null;
$foto =  isset($_FILES['foto']['name']) ? $_FILES['foto']['name'] : null;
$firma = isset($_FILES['firma']['name']) ? $_FILES['firma']['name'] : null;
$ruta = isset($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'] : 
null;
$ruta2 = isset($_FILES['firma']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['firma']['tmp_name'] 
: null;
$destino="Fotos/".uniqid(rand(),true).'_'.$foto;
$destino2="doc_signs/".uniqid(rand(),true).'_'.$firma.'.png';
$_SESSION['foto']= $foto;


If($clv_e!=""){ 
copy($ruta,$destino);
copy($ruta2,$destino2); 
$qry=mysql_query("insert into 
registros(clave_electoral,seccion,imagen,firma,estado,Id_usuario)
 values 

('".$clv_e."','".$seccion."','".$destino."','".$destino2."'
,'Activo','".$Id_u."');"
);
```

En otro archivo tengo este código que se llama `save_sign.php` que es donde me crea la imagen.

```
<?php 
$result = array();
$imagedata = base64_decode($_POST['firma']);
$filename = md5(date("dmYhisA"));
//Location to where you want to created sign image
$file_name = './doc_signs/'.$filename.'.png';
file_put_contents($file_name,$imagedata);
$result['status'] = 1;
$result['file_name'] = $file_name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo no veo tu form para comprobar si existe el atributo: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Lo otro que observo es que no hay inputs tipo file como para poder enviarlos.

Y tercero para poder enviar archivos a traves de ajax tu formulario debe ser convertido a un objeto FormData y enviarlo como data en tu request ajax; adicionalmente `processData` y `contentType` deben estar en `false`. Un ejemplo a esto sería:

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        dataType: "json",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: $(this).attr("method"),
        beforeSend: function () {},
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
        success: function (data) {}
    });
});
```

Espero que este ejemplo te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Si necesitas más info sobre los objetos FormData, te comparto este link donde se habla sobre el tema: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData